# Haskell functions in GHCi

Tags: haskell, ghci

I am completely new to Haskell. I have been trying to learn how to write functions, lets say to add two integer numbers. I am currently using GHCi to code Haskell. I tried learning from http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/functions.html, however this does not work, I get a not in scope error. I greatly appreciate any help with this. Am I supposed to not use GHCi to code haskell in order to create functions? GHCi, seems to work okay so far, for everything other than functions.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use let to declare functions in GHCI

```
ghci>let add x y = x + y
ghci>add 3 3
6
```

In general though I would advice you to open up a text editor and write your functions in there, save as .hs and open it with :l in ghci

Like this ( from RWH)

```
-- file: ch03/add.hs
add a b = a + b
```

Then:

```
ghci> :l add.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( add.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
ghci> add 1 2
3
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for the reply. Did not know that I had to use let for a function declaration. :) This worked. What if I would like to pass a list to my function and say subtract each element by 1?

Comment: You just need to add a let in front.  In general though I would advice you to open up a text editor and write your functions in there, save as .hs and open it with :l in ghci.

Comment: Once I have it saved, how do I direct GHCi to the path where .hs file is saved?

Comment: i.e. C:\Program Files (x86)\Haskell Platform\2012.4.0.0\modules

Comment: You can change the current working directory with `:cd`. Also, `:! cd` and `:! dir` might be useful.

Comment: In general, `ghci` is more like writing the body of your `main` function, line-by-line, than like writing at the top-level.